# bash + awk: extract specific information from ensemble of filles

Tags: bash, awk

I am using bash script to extract some information from log files located within the directory and save the summary in the separate file.
In the bottom of each log file, there is a table like:

```
mode |   affinity | dist from best mode
     | (kcal/mol) | rmsd l.b.| rmsd u.b.
-----+------------+----------+----------
   1       -6.961          0          0
   2       -6.797      2.908      4.673
   3       -6.639      27.93      30.19
   4       -6.204      2.949      6.422
   5       -6.111      24.92      28.55
   6       -6.058      2.836      7.608
   7       -5.986      6.448      10.53
   8        -5.95      19.32      23.99
   9       -5.927      27.63      30.04
  10       -5.916      27.17      31.29
  11       -5.895      25.88      30.23
  12       -5.835      26.24      30.36
```

from this I need to take only the value from the second column of the first line (-6.961) and add it together with the name of the log as one string in new ranking_${output}.log

```
log_name -6.961
```

so for 5 processed logs it should be something like:

```
# ranking_${output}.log
log_name1 -X.XXX
log_name2 -X.XXX
log_name3 -X.XXX
log_name4 -X.XXX
log_name5 -X.XXX
```

Here is a simple bash workflow, which takes ALL THE LINES from ranking table and saves it together with the name of the LOG file:

```
#!/bin/bash
home="$PWD"
#folder contained all *.log files
results="${home}"/results

# loop each log file and take its name + all the ranking table
 for log in ${results}/*.log; do
  log_name=$(basename "$log" .log)
  echo "$log_name" >> ${results}/ranking_${output}.log
  cat $log | tail -n 12 >> ${results}/ranking_${output}.log
done
```

Could you suggest me an AWK routine which would select only the top value located on the first line of each table?
This is an AWK example that I had used for another format, which does not work there:

```
awk -F', *' 'FNR==2 {f=FILENAME; 
                     sub(/.*\//,"",f);
                     sub(/_.*/ ,"",f);
                     printf("%s: %s\n", f, $5) }' ${results}/*.log >> ${results}/ranking_${output}.log
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `awk`. If first column contains `1` print filename and second column to file `output`:

```
awk '$1=="1"{print FILENAME, $2}' *.log > output
```

Update to remove path and suffix (.log):

```
awk '$1=="1"{sub(/.*\//,"",FILENAME); sub(/\.log/,"",FILENAME); print FILENAME, $2}'
```

Comment: thank you! generally it does the job, just one question: actually it saves not a FILENAME but its full path /Users/gleb/Documents/tutorials/dolce/results/chico_rep01.log -7.219
is it possible to modify awk to save only the name of the log (without extension): chico_rep01?

Comment: NB: I just used different function to print the ouput printf("%s: %s\n", FILENAME, $2) i order to put separator ":" between the both terms (dunno if it is better then your sollution or not) :-)

Comment: This is possible, too: `print FILENAME ":", $2`

Comment: If only there was some way to set a variable that dictates what goes between fields being output, some kind of Output Field Separator variable..... :-).